# TSQL - Dynamic column header creation based column values (Pivot/Unpivot)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, transpose, unpivot

I have to deal with the following table structure to transform it to a view like the second table in below image:  [image: table structure]

Since the column "**Var_Columns**" can contain over a hundred different values I would like some **dynamic statement** that would use those values in order to creat column headers with their according values.

Ideally the month name should be in a format like "2016-01-01" for January and so on.

I wish I could present some trial and error code but I'm already stuck at the beginning.
Therefore I created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd32b9/1) so you can have a look.

Hopefully someone has an idea how this can be solved.

Thank you,

Daniel

Comment: Your sample data doesn't seem to match the desired output. You will have to first unpivot this so you can normalize your data into rows, then do a dynamic pivot to turn this back into the columns you want.

Comment: here is an example of how to unpivot and then pivot your data.. the dynamic `Var_Columns` part should be easy to do.  In order for this to work, you will need to name your column `February` instead of `Febuary`  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/95c35/2

Comment: dynamically http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/95c35/3

Comment: thank you very much for your example. 
Is it possible to put "[ ]" around the dynamically created column headers?
Because some start or end with characters like % and so on.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using dynamic sql to derive the column names.

Creating test dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE input
    (
    [ID] int NOT NULL,
    [Version] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [RowNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Dept] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Info] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Year] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Var_Columns] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [January] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Febuary] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [March] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [April] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [May] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [June] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [July] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [August] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [September] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [October] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [November] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [December] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    )
;

INSERT INTO input
    ([ID], [Version], [RowNo],[Dept], [Info],[Year],[Var_Columns],[January],[Febuary], [March],[April],[May],[June],[July]
     ,[August],  [September] ,[October],[November],[December]
    )
VALUES
(1,2,1,'DeptA','Sheet','2016','varCol1','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'),
(1,2,2,'DeptA','Sheet','2016','varCol2','11','22','33','44','55','66','77','88','99','100','110','120'),
(1,2,3,'DeptA','Sheet','2016','varCol3','111','222','333','444','555','666','777','888','999','101','111','122'),
(2,2,1,'DeptB','Sheet','2016','varCol1','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','9','10','11','12')
;
```

The actual solution:

```
--Create a variable to hold the column names for the unpivot
DECLARE @col VARCHAR(MAX)  = '';

-- insert the distinct Var_column entries into a temp table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp; 
SELECT DISTINCT [Var_Columns] INTO #temp
FROM input

--Assign the distinct Var_column entries in the temp table to the variable @col
SELECT   @col +=  QUOTENAME([Var_Columns])+',' from #temp;

--generate the dynamic query
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = ''

SELECT  @sql = '

;WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT * 
FROM 
   (SELECT [ID], [Version], [Dept], [Info],[Year],[Var_Columns],[January],[Febuary], [March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December]
   FROM input) p
UNPIVOT
   ([Values] FOR [Month] IN 
      ([January],[Febuary], [March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December])
)AS unpvt)

SELECT [ID], [Version], [Dept], [Info],[Year],[Month], 
'+SUBSTRING(@col,1,LEN(@col)-1)+'
FROM
(SELECT *
    FROM CTE) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX([Values])
FOR Var_Columns IN ('+SUBSTRING(@col,1,LEN(@col)-1)+')
) AS PivotTable;

; '

-- prin the query and then execute.
print (@sql)
EXECUTE (@sql)

GO
```

Results:

[image]